# How do I hide the Menu Bar in my Access 2016 Database and only display running forms

Tags: forms, ms-access

I'm trying to get rid of the menu bar on my MS Access 2016 database, and only have the user able to see and use the running forms when the database is opened. Please see the picture below:

**Access Database with Menu bar**

[image: Access Database with Menu bar]

How to I go about this?

Comment: See my answer and let me know it works for you or not.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will hide ribbon (menu bar).

```
    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
```

Write above code on Startup form `Load` event.
You can also hide `Navigation Pane` (Left bar showing tables, forms, reports etc) by calling following lines

```
 Call DoCmd.NavigateTo("acNavigationCategoryObjectType")
 Call DoCmd.RunCommand(acCmdWindowHide)
```

So, the full code with `error handling` will be

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    'Hide ribbon of access window
    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo

    'select the navigation pange
    Call DoCmd.NavigateTo("acNavigationCategoryObjectType")
    'hide the selected object
    Call DoCmd.RunCommand(acCmdWindowHide)

Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
```

Comment: handy tip, thanks Harun24HR, how would you then re-show the tables,forms  and reports ?

Comment: I have also codes to show navigation pane. I will give it. Now writing from mobile phone. When I will sit on my laptop then will post.

Comment: @mattpm Looks like you could have an answer to your question if you'd turn it into an actual question. Keep in mind that new users do not have the commenting privilege and hence can only answer to actual questions.

Comment: It doesn't look like mattpm ever asked this question, so I did, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252577/how-would-i-programmatically-show-items-hidden-on-startup