# How would I programmatically show items hidden on startup?

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access database that is set to just show my forms and hide the ribbon and table explorer.
This works fine, except for me.
I want to be able to open the database from a shortcut, just as if I held down the Shift Key to bypass the startup routines.

I detect the command line parameter. I close the login form.

What all do I need to turn on to get back to a fully functioning version of Access without bothering with a shift key?

Here are a couple of candidates that I found from someone who was disabling everything. I need to turn them back on. But, I can't see how this worked in the original, and doesn't work at all for me.

```
StartUpShowStatusBar = True  // Done
AllowShortcutMenus = True
AllowFullMenus = True
AllowBuiltInToolbars = True
AllowToolbarChanges = True
AllowSpecialKeys = True
UseAppIconForFrmRpt = True
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MSAccess - Minimize the Toolbar Ribbon OnLoad()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240240/msaccess-minimize-the-toolbar-ribbon-onload)

Comment: @June7 It doesn't seem to. It shows how to hide the ribbon, and doesn't seem to deal with anything else at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have already seen [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41215431/5514747) to hide ribbon and navigation pane. I am posting here to show them again by clicking a button. Below is both code to hide and then show ribbon and navigation pane.

Codes to hide-

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo HarunErrHandler

'******************* Hide Ribbon and Navigation Pane ***************************

    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
    Call DoCmd.NavigateTo("acNavigationCategoryObjectType")
    Call DoCmd.RunCommand(acCmdWindowHide)

'*******************************************************************************

Exit Sub
HarunErrHandler:
MessageBox = MsgBox("Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbInformation, "Error")
End Sub
```

To show ribbon and left pane-

```
Private Sub cmdShow_Click()
On Error GoTo HarunErrHandler
    
'******************* Show Ribbon and Navigation Pane ***************************

    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes
    Call DoCmd.SelectObject(acTable, , True)

'*******************************************************************************

Exit Sub
HarunErrHandler:
MessageBox = MsgBox("Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbInformation, "Error")
End Sub
```

Comment: This gives me a ribbon and a main menu. But they both appear to be handicapped. For example, they only have "Home". "Create," "External Data," and "Database Tools" are still AWOL.

Comment: We're still not quite there. The "All Access Objects" panel appears on the left, but the context menu doesn't work. Right click and nothing appears. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Harun's answer, I was able to build this, which seems to bring everything back.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If CheckKeyFiles = True Then
        Me!txtUID = "workflow"
        Me!txtSID = GetSID("workflow")
    End If
    Me!txtVersionDate = "Version " & GetVersionDate()
    If Command = "develop" Then
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "Dialog_Login"
        DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, , True
        Application.SetOption "Show Status Bar", True
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowFullMenus") = True
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBuiltInToolbars") = True
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowToolbarChanges") = True
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowSpecialKeys") = True
        DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes
    End If
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Dim Response
    Response = MsgBox("Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf &     Err.Description, vbInformation, "Error")

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to give @harun24hr the credit he deserves and still mark this as the answer?

Comment: This effort ultimately failed. I was able to get everything back except the context menu on the Nav pane. If you can't right click and open a Delete or Update query without running it, it is unusable.